# opening a popup window from the address bar

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to open a page in a popup when a user writes an address to the address bar and hits enter.

What I am trying to do is in my page when a user clicks to the detail link of a news, the content opens in a popup

```
          <a id="shownews" name="shownews" rel="width:1000;height:760"  href="shownewsinpopup.php?newsid=<?php echo $newsid;?>" class="popup" style="text-decoration:none;">
```

I want to give the user the link of a specific news. Whenever user tries to open the link via writing into address bar and pressing the enter button, I want the news to be opened in a popup page with the same class as I am using in the above code.

Comment: Are you asking how, if someone types a URL to a page on your into their browser (no matter where the browser is currently pointing), you can stop that URL opening in the current window and open it in a popup instead?

Comment: I am asking if I can stop the URL opening in the current window and open it in a popup instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/" target="_blank">Link Name</a>
```

EDIT:

`<a href="www.somewebsite.com" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">`

I believe this will load your current web page in a new tab which the browser will focus on, and then load the URL which the user enters into the address bar in the current tab.

Comment: No this is not what I want to do. This is only a link which you can place in your page.

Comment: But I suppose making `target="_blank"` will open your link as a pop up window. Please excuse me if I haven't understood your question properly.

Comment: I understood what you meant now. I'm afraid I don't know how to accomplish that. Let me try googling it.

Comment: See if my edited answer helps you. Just out of curiosity, why would you want your user to manually enter the link into the address bar when they can simply click the link?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I just want to share the link of a specific news to the users like the share buttons.